# $scope of abstract state controller is not being destroyed upon leaving - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router, angularjs-scope

I have an abstract state `app`, a child state `app.dashboard`, and a login state `login` in **ionic1** application. Each state has its *template* and *controller*, except for `app` state; it only has a *controller*, but no *template*.

User is directed to `app.dashboard` state from `login` state after successful login. User is directed back to `login` on clicking logout.

The problem is, controller for `app` state is instantiated only once after login, and once user logs out and logs in again, `app` state controller is not initialized (thus preventing me from executing logic present in controller for `app` state). I am assuming, `app` state controller scope is never destroyed on logout, and that is why after subsequent logins, controller logic is not run.

Kindly discuss

Comment: is login state is child of app (like: app.login)?

Comment: From what i tried, the fact a state is abstract doesn't prevent it to have a controller and template, but you seem to contradict yourself here: "Each state has its template and controller, except for app state" compared to here "app state controller scope is never destroyed". So does `app` have a controller or not?

Comment: @SagarPanchasara `logic` state is not a child state of `app` state

Comment: @Kaddath updated. My bad. `app` state only has a controller.

Comment: need to look at router config code and how you have redirect to login state

Comment: `$state.go("login");` This logic is written in controller for `app` state